# How to get ordering for different MessagePostProcessors in SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have multiple MessagePostProcessors in SpringAMQP which i set them using SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setAfterReceivePostProcessors API , now my query is does these MessagePostProcessors are called in order I have mentioned.

Pseoudo code

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = // api returing SimpleMessageListenerContainer object 
container.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(new MessagePostProcessor[] {
                messagePostProcessors1 , messagePostProcessors2});
```

So does Spring AMQP call messagePostProcessors1 followed messagePostProcessors2 in sequence or does it randomly selects the same ?

If it randomly selects is there any way that we can order the same i.e messagePostProcessors2 always gets called after messagePostProcessors1

Answer (score 1):

Akshat , the order is based on the order that is set in the processor.Quoting the document here. When i look at the concrete implementation of the processors , i find there is a [setOrder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/postprocessor/AbstractDecompressingPostProcessor.html#setOrder-int-) method (form interface ordered i think). May be setting that in your message post processor will do the trick.

> public void setAfterReceivePostProcessors(MessagePostProcessor...
> afterReceivePostProcessors)
>
> Set a MessagePostProcessor that will be
> invoked immediately after a Channel#basicGet() and before any message
> conversion is performed. May be used for operations such as
> decompression Processors are invoked in order, depending on
> **PriorityOrder, Order and finally unordered.**

Comment: You don't have to implement `Ordered` - post processors that don't will be called after any that do (and in the order they were passed in) - so ...1 then ...2 in this case.